# Delete digital signatures with the help of itext 7.2.2 in java

Tags: java, itext7

I am trying to **delete** some **digital signatures** with the help of **itext 7.2.2 in java**, however I have not had the desired result, I found that I could use the `removeSignature()` method, however the method is not recognized, I also noticed the Maven repository does not find the jar that corresponds to this version and maybe that is why the method that helps to eliminate digital signatures does not recognize me.

I am following the example:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(pdfDoc, new FileOutputStream(new File(dest)), new StampingProperties());
signer.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.NOT_CERTIFIED);
signer.setFieldName("Signature1");
signer.removeSignature();
pdfDoc.close();
```

I appreciate any help you can give me, regards.

Comment: *"I found that I could use the `removeSignature()` method"* - where did you *find* that? As far as I know there never has been a `PdfSigner` method `removeSignature`. Have you instead tried the `PdfAcroForm` method `removeField` yet?